# Office Open XML: Drawing Dashed Line in Chart

Tags: ms-office, openxml, openxml-sdk

Using office open XML SDK I have drawn a scatter chart with smooth line but wondering how to change the line style for the series to show dashed line?

Answer (score 0):

Finally  I figured it  out using OPenXML Productivity tool. You have to change the PresetDash property to System.Dash.

```
private void MakeSeriesDashedLine(ScatterChartSeries scs)
            {
                C.ChartShapeProperties chartShapeProperties1 = new C.ChartShapeProperties();
                A.Outline outline1 = new A.Outline();
                A.PresetDash presetDash1 = new A.PresetDash() { Val = A.PresetLineDashValues.SystemDash };

                outline1.Append(presetDash1);
                chartShapeProperties1.Append(outline1);
                scs.Append(chartShapeProperties1);
            }
```